# Rolling a dice $5$ times

Tags: probability, proof-verification

> Rolling a dice $5$ times find the probability that we will get the continuum:

- A. $12345$
- B. $1234$
- C. $434$

---

**My attempt:**

- A: for each throwing there are $5$ possibilities so 
  $P(1)=P(2)=P(3)=P(4)=P(5)=\frac 1 6\Longrightarrow$ we are looking for $P(1)\cdot P(2)\cdot P(3)\cdot P(4)\cdot P(5)=(\frac{1}{6})^5=1/7776$
- B: $P(1)=P(2)=P(3)=P(4)=\frac 1 6\Longrightarrow$ we are looking for $P(1)\cdot P(2)\cdot P(3)\cdot P(4)=(\frac{1}{6})^4=1/1296$ now we will multiply the result by two because the series could be here $\underline{1}\underline{2}\underline{3}\underline{4}\underline{}$ or here $\underline{}\underline{1}\underline{2}\underline{3}\underline{4}$ so the final result will be $2/1296$
- C:$P(4)=P(3)=P(4)=\frac{1}{6}$ so $P(4)\cdot P(3)\cdot P(4)=(\frac{1}{6})^3=1/216$ now we will multiply the result by three because the series could be here $\underline{4}\underline{3}\underline{4}\underline{}\underline{}$ or here 
  $\underline{}\underline{4}\underline{3}\underline{4}\underline{}$ or here $\underline{}\underline{}\underline{4}\underline{3}\underline{4}$

This is correct?

Comment: only the first   is correct.

Comment: I think that *continuum* means the results must be one after the other

Comment: @sirfoga Yes you are right

Comment: You are counting $43434$ twice in example $C$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In part C, you have overcounted because  $43434$ fits both $\underline{434\cdot\cdot}$ and $\underline{\cdot\cdot434}$. You should therefore subtract the probability of getting $\underline{43434}$, which is $1/6^5$, so the answer will be $3 (1/6^3) - 1/6^5$.

Answer (score -4):

Assuming it's a *fair* die and it has actually *6* faces then

- $P(1,2,3,4,5) = \frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{6} = \left( \frac{1}{6} \right) ^ 5 = \frac{1}{6^5}$
- $P(1,2,3,4) = \frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{6} \cdot 2 = 2 \cdot \frac{1}{6^4}$
- $P(1,2,3,4) = \frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{6} \cdot 3  - 1 (\text{the event } 43434)= 3 \cdot \frac{1}{6^3} - 1$

Comment: No. You are counting $43434$ twice in the third example.

Comment: is it allowed ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "allowed", but your answer is wrong.